# My prime number generator crashes and is closed by Windows 10

Tags: c++

I have used codeblocks in the past also but never I faced such a problem.

I wrote a prime number generator between numbers 1 to 1000 and when I click on build > build and run, I get a dialog, "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly..." and I have only one option, that is to close the program.

After I close the program, what I see on the console window is "Process returned 255 (0xFF)". When I close the console window, I see white text highlighted with red saying "process terminated with status -1073741510".

The same program used to run perfectly before I had resetted my pc. It is running on Windows 10.

Any help will be appreciated.

My code is -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int facts = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 1001; i++) {
    facts = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < (i + 1); i++) {
      if(i % j == 0) {
        facts  ;
      }
    }
    if(facts > 2) {
      cout<<i;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A [MCVE] that reproduces your problem would be nice.

Comment: Your posted code is missing operators and would not compile, and it's C++, not C.

Comment: actually I tried that program with a ".cpp" extension otherwise it would give me an error in the first line itself, "#include <iostream>" whereas I get no errors while building it. I wrote c by mistake here. And the operators, I would be glad if you could tell where is my mistake

Comment: You're still missing an operator: `test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:9:12: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     facts  ;`

Comment: Disable avast if you are using that.

Comment: I noticed the operator was missing because of my browser, I use uc. Now I switched to chrome

Comment: For some unknown reason it looks like the copy paste lost all the ++ operators. The op put ones back in the for()

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Look: `+(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/???/src/a.out 

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x0000000000400702 in main () at test.cpp:8
8    if(i % j == 0) {
+(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400702 in main () at test.cpp:8`

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j < (i + 1); i++) ` should be `for(int j = 2; j < (i + 1); j++)` then change `(facts > 2)` to `(facts > 1)`

Comment: Is there any possible fix for this program? I use the ditto same logic in python and it runs fine

Comment: @Thomas The fix is to read the answer you've been given and correct your code accordingly. This may or may not (seem to) work in Python, but that's irrelevant because this is C++... where division by 0 is UB, not that it is mathematically well-defined anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a debugger? I took your code, added the missing `++` in front of `facts` in the inner loop, and look:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -ggdb test.cpp
$ gdb ./a.out
```

```
+(gdb) run

Starting program: /home/???/src/a.out 

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x0000000000400702 in main () at test.cpp:8
8               if(i % j == 0) {
+(gdb)
```

If I add a diagnostic `cout << i << ' ' << j << std::endl` just before that line, all that is ever printed is this...

```
0 0
```

...right before `gdb` fails out with the `SIGFPE`. So, the loop fails on the 1st try. Why? Because modulo is the other side of division, the quoted line attempts to divide by zero. You can't divide by zero. [Do not try to divide by zero.](https://i.eprci.net/div-zero-house-4)

Why? Well - as well as causing endless debates among (armchair?) mathematicians, - in C and C++, dividing by zero is one of many oopses that invoke **undefined behaviour**. You need to learn this concept, early and well. The compiler is not required to stop you doing such things. But the act renders your whole program invalid and prone to explode. My CPU raises a hardware exception. Yours might do the same, might do something else... UB means the program **can** do *anything* - including seemingly working fine till it mysteriously fails in an unrelated area and leaves you chasing red herrings for hours until you find the embarrassing cause. *Trust me.* That's why we don't invoke UB.

There are probably other errors in your code, but this is the most obvious - and easy to find - one. And [as **drescherjm** pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053692/codeblocks-not-compiling-my-programs#comment65457093_39053692)...

> `for(int j = 0; j < (i + 1); i++)` should be `for(int j = 2; j < (i + 1); j++)` then change `(facts > 2)` to `(facts > 1)`

...the attempted divide-by-0 is happening because your numbers are wrong.

> The same program used to run perfectly before I had resetted my pc. It is running on Windows 10.

Again: *undefined behaviour means anything can happen*. It might start *seeming to* work again tomorrow or when the wind direction changes just right. That doesn't mean anything. Code invoking UB is ill-formed and must be avoided at all costs.